# Get best Serie from an Array using for

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

There is an array I've got and I'm trying to get best Serie from it (some highest quantity of steps that are bigger than the standart value)

I tried this code, but it doesn't work properly. It just shows me days in the month I chose

```
    void bestSeries(int goalByStepsPerDay) {
        int currentSeries = 0;
        int finalSeries = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
            if (goalByStepsPerDay >= i) {
                if (currentSeries++ > finalSeries) {
                    finalSeries = currentSeries;
                }
                } else {
                    currentSeries = 0;
                }
            }
        System.out.println("Best Series are:");
        System.out.println(finalSeries);
    }
```

Comment: I assume that `days` is your array since you use its length for the loop condition.  You never access it outside of that loop condition.  I have no idea what you are trying to do. There is an array - array of what?  trying to get best series - what is a series in this context?  highest quantity of steps - what are steps in this context?  bigger than standard value - what is a standard value in this context?

Comment: Perhaps [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Post code that creates and populates the `days` array. Then post code that calls method `bestSeries`. Then post the expected value for `finalSeries` for the sample value of `goalByStepsPerDay`.